# xr_usb_serial_common limited to 32 devices

Tags: linux, drivers

I'm using 64 serial devices connected to one machine with *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*.

All devices are from Exar Corp. It worked like a charm with 32 devices but failed with 64. Only `32 /dev/ttyXRUSB*` got created.

Dmesg error some times:

```
no more free xr_usb_serial devices
```

Google didn't get me any results and after many trial & error this solved the problem. So maybe someone will find this information useful:

1. Downloaded driver source from exar
2. In `xr_usb_serial_common.h` I changed line 30 to

   ```
    #define XR_USB_SERIAL_TTY_MINORS               64
   ```
3. Compile, `insmod` and disabled/blacklisted old driver.

So it works, but I don't know exactly what I've caused and if there any side effects?

Comment: Probably no side effects: The driver needs to reserve space to hold information for the devices. Now you've allocated more space, which is wasteful for those not needing as many devices (most people won't), but otherwise harmless.

Comment: Thanks :-) Seems that no problems occured since two days.